# Can we control packing layouts with parameters in GraphLayout?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, undocumented

[`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) takes a complex specification including vertex, edge and packing layouts.  These often have sub-options to control the details of the layout.

It is reasonable to expect packing layouts to have sub-options to control things such as the tightness of packing.  Can we pass sub-options to packing layouts?  Is there a way to control packing tightness or other parameters?

---

Why do I think this should be possible?

Here's a graph illustrating a complex `GraphLayout` specification.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 5, 3 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.2}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Capsule", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 GraphLayout -> {
     "VertexLayout" -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "LeafDistance" -> 0.5}, 
     "PackingLayout" -> "ClosestPacking"}
 ]
```

[image]

When using an incorrect sub-option, Mathematica usually reports an error that includes the valis sub-option names. For example, if we misspell "LeafDistance" above, we get

> Graph::moptx: Method option LeaDistance in LayeredDrawing is not one of `{LayerSizeFunction,LeafDistance,Orientation,RootVertex,Rotation}`.

These are all the documented sub-options, plus an undocumented one: `"Rotation"`. How to use it is easy to guess: try `"Rotation" -> Pi/2`.

We can try to discover packing layout sub-options in the same way. If I use `"PackingLayout" -> {"ClosestPacking", foo -> 1}`, then I get

> Graph::moptx: Method option foo in Automatic is not one of `{Padding,PaddingFunction,PolyonimoNumber}`.

This indicates that there should be sub-options (although polyo**m**i**n**o is misspelt).

But trying to pass any of these sub-options causes the graph to fail to render. In fact just trying `"PackingLayout" -> {"ClosestPacking"}` (i.e. adding braces) causes the graph to fail to render.  I get

[image]

**Question:** Can we somehow make use of these sub-options (if they are indeed implemented), either through documented or undocumented means?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you could send a suggestion for this.

Comment: @halmir Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

When using `GraphPlot` instead of `Graph`, these sub-options work.  But `GraphPlot` has other limitations compared to `Graph`, unfortunately. I am still looking for ways to control packing with `Graph`.

```
GraphPlot[
   {1 -> 2, 1 -> 5, 3 -> 4},
   Method -> "LayeredDrawing",
   PackingMethod -> {"ClosestPacking", Padding -> #}
   ] & /@ {1, 2}
```

[image]